# Rails Video Autoplay Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, html5-video

I'm using the `video_tag` to display a video like so:

```
<%= video_tag "tech4.mp4", autoplay: true %>
```

Which produces HTML that looks like this:

```
<video src="(big source file)" autoplay="autoplay"></video>
```

The `autoplay` works in Firefox, but not in Chrome or Safari. I figured out that the autoplay works when I change the HTML (in browser) to:

```
<video src="(big source file)" autoplay></video>
```

How can I get that output from the `video_tag`? I've tried `:autoplay`, `autoplay: ''`, `autoplay: nil`, but nothing works.

Comment: my video was not playing with these solutions alone, I also needed to add `muted: true` to the attributes as discussed in this other Stack Overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55508490/7573223)

Answer (score 4):

I just tried:

```
autoplay: :autoplay,
loop: :loop,
```

in Chrome 46.0.2490.86 and Safari 9.0.1, and it works.

It produces:

```
<video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" ...
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution

```
<%= video_tag(["video.mp4"], :size => "320x240", :autoplay => true, :loop => true) %>
```

I know it is a long time. I hope this can help others that have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this issue and found a complete solution:

```
video_tag(source_url, autoplay: :autoplay, loop: :loop, muted: :muted, class: "home_video")
```

found via [Medium article](https://medium.com/swlh/add-a-background-video-to-your-landing-page-in-rails-5-7b9c459023bc)