# Rails error: Autoplay is only working sometimes for video_tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, html5-video

I'm using Carrierwave to upload video files and have both `autoplay` and `loop` set to `true` for my `video_tag`. The video plays automatically after uploading it initially but only shows the first frame of the video after I've refreshed the page.

Source for video_tag:

`video_tag post.video_url.to_s, autoplay: true, loop: true, class: :standard_post_video`

https://github.com/ethanwilkins/simplr/blob/2c07884d153192566ded30bd020c06237747f401/app/views/posts/_card.html.erb#L87

I'm also using Nginx and Unicorn. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add

> muted: 'muted'

in video_tag

```
video_tag post.video_url.to_s, autoplay: true, loop: true, muted: 'muted', class: :standard_post_video
```

See Docs: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Chrome's autoplay policies are simple:

- Muted autoplay is always allowed.
- Autoplay with sound is allowed if:

  - User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
  - On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning
  - the user has previously play video with sound.
  - On mobile, the user has [added the site to their home screen].
  - Top frames can delegate autoplay permission to their iframes to allow autoplay with sound.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `muted: "muted"` to my `video_tag` allowed me to check if the video is playing and then call `play()` if necessary. This resolved my issue:

```
    <%= video_tag post.video_url.to_s, autoplay: true, loop: true, muted: "muted", class: :standard_post_video, id: "standard_post_video_#{post.id}" %>
    <script>
      var video = $('#video').get(0);
      if (video.paused) {
        video.play();
      }
    </script>
```

Commit: https://github.com/ethanwilkins/simplr/commit/4eea13ee610b4744f555cfba3696da6ac492b622